# Delay Submit until then function completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I have the following JS code. 
Problem is the the form always submit before the then function.
I want the form to only submit after the then function.

How do I do that? Thanks

```
$('#form').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  html2canvas(document.getElementById('uty'), {
    useCORS: true,
  }).then(function (canvas) {
      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      document.getElementById('input').value = img;
 });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you can store a reference to the `form` element in the outer `submit` handler function, then call `submit()` on that within the `then()` block. Something like this:

```
$('#form').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = this;

  html2canvas(document.getElementById('uty'), {
    useCORS: true,
  }).then(function(canvas) {
    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.getElementById('input').value = img;
    form.submit();
 });    
});
```

Note I'm calling the DOM `submit` function, not jQuery's. jQuery's would re-run the submit handler, the DOM's won't.

Comment: Thank you @rory-mccrossan for the answer and the speed. It works. I thought the purpose of [then] is to delay every other thing until the [then] function completes. Can you please explain why the form submits before the then? Thanks

Comment: It's because the form submission has already begun before you make your async request to `html2canvas`. Due to that call being asynchronous, the form submission does not wait for it to complete. To fix this you need to call `preventDefault()` on the submit event itself, but in turn this completely stops the submission, regardless of the state of the async call. The above solution fixes this by using jQuery to stop the submission as soon as it's made, then submitting the form again through the DOM submit method when the async operation completes.